# How to disable onChange for a number of elements, change then, then enable onChange in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of input elements on a page.  Each input element has an onchange event that triggers an ajax call to the server. I want to disable all these onchanges then make some programatic changes to the elements (reset them), then re-enable these onchange events. I want only one ajax call to happen as a result of this.

How do I do this using JQuery?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing an input elements value through [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) doesn't trigger a [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) so you can set your values and then trigger the change event at the end by hand:

```
$('#a').val('where is');
$('#b').val('pancakes house?');
$('#a').change(); // This is the only change event
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Qd2Ad/

From the [fine manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> **change**
>   The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

There is no focus change when you just call `val` so there is no event.

Comment: thanks!

The problem was with sliders on my page.  Apparently the change event is fired for sliders upon a programatic change. To fix it I used:

Comment: thanks!

The problem was with sliders on my page.  Apparently the change event is fired for sliders upon a programatic change. To fix it I used:

if (event.originalEvent) {

here is the reference: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-a-sliders-value-without-triggering-the-change-event